# Maths Function properties

Tags: functions

this may be quite a simple question but please can someone let me know if everything written on this image is correct? Thank you, any help is much appreciated. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Sozz.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

yes, the mathematics written on the paper is correct.

Unfortunately the notation inverse function is very very confusing.

Students get confused by for example the difference between $$ \sin ^{-1} x $$ and $$ \frac {1}{\sin x}$$  where the first one is the inverse sine function and the second one is the co-secant function, which are totally different functions.

After some practice it gets easier to find out which is which from the context.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes the false ‘arcsin(x) = cosec(x)’ statement is what led me to find out if ‘f^-1(x) is not equal to (f(x))^-1’ is true for all functions aswell as trig functions.

Comment: @user564900 Thanks for your attention and understanding .